# At wit's end trying to figure out this Minimax algorithm for Tic-Tac-Toe

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I've been sitting here for many hours trying to implement this Minimax algorithm into my tic-tac-toe game and although I am making progress, this bug I've encountered is very demoralizing and I'm hoping someone can point me towards the right direction.

The problem is that the Computer is not making the correct moves when I start the game, and I can beat it fairly easily.

Here is my code for Minimax:

```
function minimax(currentBoard, player, depth) {

    var emptySquares = currentBoard.filter(square => !isNaN(square));

    if (checkForWin(currentBoard, playerO)) {

        return 10 - depth;
    }
    else if (checkForWin(currentBoard, playerX)) {

        return depth - 10;
    }
    else if (emptySquares.length == 0) {

        return 0;
    }

    var moves = [];
    var scores = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < emptySquares.length; i++) {

        let copyBoard = currentBoard.slice();

        copyBoard[emptySquares[i]] = player;

        player = (player == playerX ? playerO : playerX);

        let result = minimax(copyBoard, player, depth++)

        scores.push(result);
        moves.push(emptySquares[i]);

    }

    let bestMove;

    if (player == playerO) {

    let bestScore = -10000;

        for (let i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
            if (scores[i] > bestScore) {
                bestScore = scores[i];
                bestMove = moves[i];
            }
        }

        return bestMove;
    }

    else {

    let bestScore = 10000;

        for (let i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
            if (scores[i] < bestScore) {
                bestScore = scores[i];
                bestMove = moves[i];
            }
        }

        return bestMove;
    }
}
```

Here is the code for checking for wins:

```
function checkForWin(currentBoard, player) {
    for (let i = 0; i < wins.length; i++) {

        let counter = 0;

        for (let j = 0; j < wins[i].length; j++) {
            if (currentBoard[wins[i][j]] === player) {

                counter++;

                if (counter === 3) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Really bothers me that I am stuck for so long and can't seem to find a solution myself, I'm hoping someone can help. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Why not just start fresh, following someone else's working code to understand the possible differences?

Comment: That would be my last resort and I don’t feel good about copying code even if it’s just to help me figuring out my problem. I feel like I’m close to solving this and just need a pointer or two to guide me towards the bug. I just want to know whether it’s this algorithm that’s the problem or something outside of it... if someone confirms this algorithm is good the I will need to check else where.